# Get user response of Word save prompt?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto, office-addins

**Background:** I am creating a VSTO Word Add-In using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2015.

**Problem:** When closing a document, I want the user to be prompted to save it. Below is the standard command I keep seeing everywhere and that I want to use:

```
thisDoc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSaveChanges)
```

However, I want to store in a variable the option that the user has selected (i.e. Yes, No, or Cancel). How can I do this?

I know how to do it using a Message Box (see code below) but would prefer to use wdPromptToSaveChanges.

```
Dim userSaveResponse As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Do you want to save this doc?", vbYesNoCancel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close doesn't return anything, and I'm not aware of any fields that are changed during a save except `Document.Saved` (which, when false, would not tell you whether it was a No or Cancel) but at that point the document is closed and probably can't be accessed.

One thing you can do, is call `thisDoc.Save()`, and if the user cancels out of it (or any other error occurs), a COMException will be thrown. Otherwise, it succeeded.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be the case. The user's choice is not returned but a 4198 error will result if the user hits Cancel. Here's some more info for others: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196343.aspx